# viewWillAppear not getting invoked in an UITableViewController

Tags: iphone

I have got one problem with the UITableViewController... The viewWillAppear method is not getting invoked when i try to push the The table view controller in to a navigationcontroller...

can anyone provide a solution for this ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should have been called.

Once I had a similar problem and couldn't understand why isn't it called.
The solution was to write it correctly:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}
```

In my case I forgot to add the BOOL argument...

Comment: It's amazing how many times writing the code correctly would have solved my problems :)